# Does "gram negative" generally indicate highly antibiotics resistant bacteria strains?

Tags: terminology, bacteria, antibiotics, resistance

I must admit that I am an absolute medical layman, trying to keep myself informed at best though.

Today I had a consultation at my dermatologist about a bad healing wound I have, to talk about the results of a swab they did last week.
It turned out that the wound is infected by several bacteria, and he said

> Worst is that we found some *gram negative* bacteria ... (some other facts) ... , pseudomonas in particular.

Back at home I looked up what *gram negative* actually means, and found out to my astonishment, that it mainly (merely?) means the reaction of these bacteria in a coloring test.

Of course I looked up pseudomonas as well, and it's a fact that these are well known to be highly resistant to antibiotics (and my doctor explained that as well of course), and sometimes hard to medicate.

Now I am wondering, why he mentioned *gram negative* in 1st place.

**Is it that the *gram negative* reaction in general indicates such hard to medicate, antibiotics resistant strains of bacteria?**

<sub>Please excuse my laymans wording, I'm also not a native english speaker. Feel free to edit my question for better wording.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[Gram positivity/negativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_stain) is sort of a historical classification that comes down to an ability to separate bacteria types without knowing what that separation really meant physically.

Of course, what really matters isn't whether or not a bacterial species takes up a particular stain, but rather that the reason that they stain well or poorly is because they have a different type of outer coat. [Gram-positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-positive_bacteria) bacteria have a thick peptidoglycan (sugars+amino acids) wall. [Gram-negative bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-negative_bacteria) have a second membrane on the outside, and typically a thinner peptidoglycan layer in the middle.

There is some complexity in this because not all bacteria necessarily follow the same staining "rule" by their coat, but it works as a rough characterization for many species and is quick and cheap.

Some antibiotics target the peptidoglycan wall, so they are most effective against Gram-positive bacteria ([penicillin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penicillin) is an example).

However, there is nothing that says a Gram-positive bacteria can't also have antibiotic resistance. *Staphylococcus* are a common Gram-positive pathogenic strain, and you may have heard of [MRSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methicillin-resistant_Staphylococcus_aureus), a particularly troublesome antibiotic-resistant Staph strain.

Comment: Ty for the detailed explanation. Yes I've heard about _Staphylococcus_ and these developped the antibiotics resistance mainly in clinical / hospital environments (strong survivors these lil' beasts :-P).

Answer (score 1):

Seems I found the answer about the correlation of *gram negative* test and high resistance against antibiotics.

From Wikipedia **[Gram-negative bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-negative_bacteria)** (emphasis mine):

> Gram-negative bacteria are found everywhere, in virtually all
> environments on Earth that support life. The gram-negative bacteria
> include the model organism Escherichia coli, as well as many
> pathogenic bacteria, such as Pseudomonas aeruginosa, Chlamydia
> trachomatis, and Yersinia pestis. **They are an important medical
> challenge, as their outer membrane protects them from many antibiotics
> (including penicillin); detergents that would normally damage the
> peptidoglycans of the (inner) cell membrane; and lysozyme, an
> antimicrobial enzyme produced by animals that forms part of the innate
> immune system. Additionally, the outer leaflet of this membrane
> comprises a complex lipopolysaccharide (LPS) whose lipid A component
> can cause a toxic reaction when these bacteria are lysed by immune
> cells.** This toxic reaction can include fever, an increased respiratory
> rate, and low blood pressure — a life-threatening condition known as
> septic shock.

Now it's clear for me, why *gram-negative* was mentioned by my dermatologist in 1st place.
It is a general indication of antibiotic resistance of bacteria strains.